# Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system)

I have been having a tough time getting a new computer (Lenovo h430) that came with windows 8 to dual boot with ubuntu linux.  I can get ubuntu to install from a usb drive and can use the live system (ubuntu 12.10) but dual booting has not worked.
I have cruised the internet and tried a number of solutions such as easybcd 2.2 and boot repair under linux.  I have also gone into the setup screen to try and fix it but the lenovo acromyms in the setup are not illuminating for me.
Does anyone know of a clear set of instructions for installing ubuntu on a machine delivered with windows 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the new machine has an EFI firmware, a drive with a GUID partition table (GPT), or both.

If you enter firmware setup there may be a legacy BIOS mode that you can use.  You should also check the [Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for methods of dealing with EFI firmware.  The most simple suggestion from that page appears to be to use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix the issue.

Since boot repair has not worked for you so far, make sure that you are trying to install the 64bit release of Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems installing Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8 but this tutorial helped me a lot.

Maybe it will help you as it clearly explains how to install Ubuntu 12.10 using easyBCD in Windows 8:

[Dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI hardware](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/)